# vba error disappears when running "step into" with locals windows open

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a small piece of vba-code running perfect in office 2010. When running in office 365, it gives an "index out of range"-error, but not when I step into the code with the Outmail-variabele open in the locals-window. The aim of the code is to attach one or more pdf's to a template mail.

The error is when Display in yellow.

```
Sub Mailing()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim onderworpenNL As String
Dim onderworpenFR As String

onderworpenNL = "some text"

onderworpenFR = "some text"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\res.sys.shared....\macromail_mail1.oft")
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "dd@dd.com"
    .to = Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    .Subject = "some text: " & Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & " - " & "account: " & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACENAAM", Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)))
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEWHK", Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)))
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEREDENNL", Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row)))
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEREDENFR", Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row)))
    If Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Yes" Then .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEONDERWORPENNL", onderworpenNL)
    If Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "No" Then .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEONDERWORPENNL", "")
    If Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Yes" Then .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEONDERWORPENFR", onderworpenFR)
    If Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "No" Then .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "REPLACEONDERWORPENFR", "")
    On Error Resume Next
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & ".pdf"
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & "_1.pdf"
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & "_2.pdf"
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & "_3.pdf"
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & "_4.pdf"
    .Attachments.Add "\\res.sys.shared....\retour\" & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & "_5.pdf"
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: I added it to my question. Sorry. It is when stepping out of "Display". When display is in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\res.sys.shared....\macromail_mail1.oft")
```

For

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

and it shall work in both excels

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, with this solution, how can I still refer to my template?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thoght it was an empty template, in this case, confirm if you can full access it from your computer and if you can open it with outlook 365 and hit "save as" just to update the file

Comment: I have access to the template. I resaved it, but the issue stays the same.

Comment: When I comment out the lines attaching the templates,everything works fine. Off course, no templates attached.

Comment: I tested the code with a template and it worked fine on Office 365, can you make your template avaible for download?

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. It's a bit difficult to share the template, as it's from my employer. However, it's a very basic HTML-template with some text and the words that the macro has to replace. Honestly, I don't think the template is the probem. Fact is that the code works here as well, but only when I do it step by step with the locals window open and the Outmail-variable expanded. Strange :)